# Tagging content for search with Google

Tags: google-search, tags

I am working on a website that will contain a lot of content and I would like to add ability to tag content, just like Stackexchange does, where each question can be tagged by maximum 5 tags.

Now, I would like to use Google to search for all pages tagged by certain tag.

I thought of enclosing each tag inside special characters like this:

*tags: {mytag},{google},{tags}*

and then seach for **{mytag}** in Google.

However, it seems Google ignores special characters. 
What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this, however, assuming that you are referring to a [Google Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse/) for your site, the simplest way would be as follows:

1. Maintain a page for each of your tags with a URI similar to `/tagged/mytag` (where `mytag` is a given tag - each tag should have its own page)
2. Allow documents which match a tag to be indexed by ID or slug under `/tagged/mytag/myid` or `/tagged/mytag/mydocument` and ensure that documents include a [canonical URL](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)
3. When a "tag search" option is specified, append the following to the search query string: `inurl:/tagged/mytag` (where `mytag` is whichever tag the user specifies)

You can test to see which results will display by searching `site:example.com inurl:/tagged/mytag` at Google (in this case, the format demonstrated should work with a default WordPress installation).

This should present users with a list of results which (a) match their query string and (b) are tagged as the user has specified.

**Note:** The [OpenSearch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSearch) specification references a ["tags" element](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1#The_.22Tags.22_element) - to the best of my knowledge, however, this element is not presently supported with Google searches (though many browsers - including Google Chrome - already support some OpenSearch-powered functionality).